# Get JavaScript command executed while tap on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I need to get or capture the JavaScript command executed when I tap on a button or a menu into a web from `UIWebView`

I don't know wich functtion uses a site to upload a file so I need to capture it.

The purpose of this is to make a javascript file upload by just tapping a `UIButton`. The JS executes into the `UIWebView` with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"js_code_here"];`

There is any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the HTML if you know the element id or class associated with the button/menu.

Answer (score 0):

try this to call js file within xcode project.,

```
- (void)markHighlightedString
{
    // The JS File
    NSString *filePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HighlightedString" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""]; // your js file name
    NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *jsString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // The JS Function
    NSString *startSearch   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stylizeHighlightedString()"]; // your js function which you want to call
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];
}
```

Hope this helps,
thanks. Happy coding